# Optimize Python by restructuring imports

Tags: python, performance

I'm trying to boost up the speed of the program. Besides removing redundancy, using loop instead of executing each line, I'm wondering if putting all methods in one main program to call them, or divide those methods into other smaller programs, then import those smaller programs and call in the main program, makes a difference in speed?

Additionally, see below 2 kinds of import, I suppose the first one is faster?

1. ```
   from ProgramA import MethodX

   MethodX.do something
   ```
2. ```
   import ProgramA

   ProgramA.MethodX.do something
   ```

Comment: Why is this tagged Java?

Comment: Er.. where is the program?

Comment: The first one is normally faster if the `do something` is executed mulitple times as there is one less hash value to compute and lookup, the one for ProgramA). Is this in CPython? Pypy? Jython?

Comment: @Anthon However, shaving a few milliseconds from the program's execution time probably isn't the kind of performance improvement the OP is actually looking for.

Comment: For desperate, rabid, hard-core last-inch optimization of a really tight main loop, *unrolling* it (i.e. converting an explicit loop to repeated sequential steps) could bring performance gains, i.e. the opposite of what you appear to have been doing; but strongly recommend against that except as a final touch after you have optimized everything else.

Comment: Out of curiosity @user3787620: did you run a profiler on your code to convince yourself that optimization is *actually* needed/beneficial? (As @ PangeaCake mentioned, you may want to edit your OP and include the relevant code).

Comment: The program is very large, I use python to engage sqlite database. It runs fast in local computer, but when I put it in network drive, it is much slower. However, other other program our company is using is much faster and that db is much bigger. I was wondering if it is something wrong with my code to slow it down during calling. Now I am thinking if there could be some private tunneling for our company program while it is being executed.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is no. When you are talking about the speed of your program. None of the things you mentioned really matter. The importing difference is not going to make your program significantly faster or putting your code in a for loop. If you want to learn about what really matters for program efficiency search Big O notation and read some things on that. But for example consider trying to find the greatest common denominator.

The first thing that comes to your head for finding the GCD of two numbers is something like this...

```
def GCD (num1, num2):
    for i in reversed(range(1, num1)):
         if (num1 % i == 0) and (num2 % i == 0):
             return i
```

Now, this program would solve your problem. But it is not the **best** way to solve the problem. The best way is called Euclid's algorithm... For example.

```
def GCD(num1, num2):
    if (num2 == 0):
       return num1
    else:
       return GCD(num2, num1 % num2)
```

This algorithm is better. So the moral of the story is, when you are talking program speed and efficiency, you are trying to find the best way to solve the problem like the examples above. Little things like what you are talking about above really don't matter. However, if you are really in need for more speed go look into multiprocessing and parallel computing.

Comment: Also maybe point to profiling as the way to find the bottlenecks, particularly where intuition clearly isn't helping.